# Android - Save Stats (from Tamagotchi App)

Tags: android, save, sharedpreferences

I have a class named Stats, and a Main Activity.
The Stats class have some values like: life, hunger, sleep, level and so on with Getter and Setter methods.

How can i save my Stats after the App is closed and load the Stats when the app is started? (the stats class is no activity)
I tried it with SharedPreference, but I failed it. Should I try it with something else?

Solution: I took a class with static methods. Static because I wanted to have getter and setter in it. It would go even without, but it's too complicated. Then pass the context of the application and the value at the setters. And the context in the getters.

```
package at.android.dertestloerk;

import android.content.Context;
import android.content.SharedPreferences;
import android.preference.PreferenceActivity;

public class SettingsLoerg extends PreferenceActivity {

    private static final String KEY_HUNGER = "key_hunger";
    private static final String KEY_SLEEP = "key_sleep";
    private static final String KEY_LIFE = "key_life";
    private static final String KEY_LEVEL = "key_level";

    public static SharedPreferences getPrefs(Context context) {

        return context.getSharedPreferences("PreferenceLoerg", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

    }


    public static int getHunger(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(KEY_HUNGER, -1);
    }

    public static void setHunger(int hunger, Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(KEY_HUNGER, hunger).commit();
    }

    public static int getSleep(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(KEY_SLEEP, -1);
    }

    public static void setSleep(int sleep, Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(KEY_SLEEP, sleep).commit();
    }

    public static int getLife(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(KEY_LIFE, -1);
    }

    public static void setLife(int life, Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(KEY_LIFE, life).commit();
    }

    public static int getLevel(Context context) {
        return getPrefs(context).getInt(KEY_LEVEL, -1);
    }

    public static void setLevel(int level, Context context) {
        getPrefs(context).edit().putInt(KEY_LEVEL, level).commit();
    }
}
```

Comment: no you shouldn't try something else just yet. show us the saving sequence and any pertinent logcats and let's find out why it "failed" to produce result.

Comment: do you have more the one Stats in the App or only one instance?
what went wrong with SharedPreferences?

Comment: I see 3 options here: 1) SharedPreferences 2) SQLite database 3) External file with name you like

Comment: Regarding SharedPrefrences , there should be no problem putting a small amount of key/value in and restoring them later, from my experience most of the problems are either not getting the preferences correctly or forgetting to commit() the editor.

Comment: i added the code parts. Im very new in android programming.

Comment: added Solution. found it after a few hours research